# WebSphere Process Server and parallel task

Tags: web-services, websphere, parallel-processing, websphere-6.1

We are designing a system that will use WebSphere Process Server.

At one point we need to call two web services and then combined the results.

We plan to create a parallel fork and then call each web service from its' own fork.

Question is how will this run? Will WPS call the first web service and wait for an answer, and then call the second. or will the two calls be made at the same time?

Previously, we have used Windows Workflow (WF). In WF 3.0 (old version) you could define parallel tasks. But each workflow was run by a single thread so it was not really parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should provide you with the answers that you are after.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.bpc.doc/doc/bpc/t5_parallel_paths.html

HTH

Manglu